# Java process sleeps after 397 seconds

Tags: java, process, ffmpeg, jvm

This code records video only ~397 seconds from live stream, after stream terminates. File size ~20 Megabytes. Java and ffmpeg processes are not terminated. Centos 6, Oracle JDK 8. Without java ffmpeg recording is not terminated. What is may be problem? May be any limits for JVM or OS?

```
public class FFMpegLauncher extends Thread {
    private Process pr;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FFMpegLauncher launcher = new FFMpegLauncher();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.addShutdownHook(launcher);
        try {
            if(args.length > 0) {
                String cameraUid = args[0];
                String rtspURL = "rtsp://otherhost/" + cameraUid;
                launcher.pr = rt.exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i " + rtspURL + " -vcodec copy -r 15 -f flv out.mp4");
                launcher.pr.waitFor();
            } else {
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does `ffmpeg` produce any output to standard output/error when you run it the regular way from the command line? Because here you're not consuming the output. When its buffer fills up, it will block.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, how to consume the output?

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder` and call `inheritIO()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark! :)